# Google Chrome quits on open

Tags: mac, google-chrome

When I open Google Chrome, it shuts down all by itself. This is on a MacBook Pro Retina. I reinstalled Chrome, but the problem still exists.

OS X version : 10.10.3

```
Process:               Google Chrome [17568]
Path:                  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Identifier:            com.google.Chrome
Version:               43.0.2357.81 (2357.81)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Google Chrome [17568]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-06-09 02:29:56.144 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        9DF5D0E6-E127-AC6E-F7C3-B6DB4325D031

Sleep/Wake UUID:       04CFEE8F-376E-4443-9554-A7F9454E8111

Time Awake Since Boot: 390000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       13000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        17  Chrome_IOThread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000d0

VM Regions Near 0xd0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010ec0d000-000000010ec0e000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Thread 0:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff959944de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9599364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff98b70eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff98b7037b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff98b6fbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9129456f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff912942ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9129412b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aabd9bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aabcf68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ac88987 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 666
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ac84f76 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 119
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ad36a63 -[NSAlert runModal] + 144
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ad6e2cd __55-[NSPersistentUIRestorer promptToIgnorePersistentState]_block_invoke + 1037
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ad6de7e -[NSApplication _suppressFinishLaunchingFromEventHandlersWhilePerformingBlock:] + 28
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ad6de1d -[NSPersistentUIRestorer promptToIgnorePersistentState] + 247
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aac4c7a -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:] + 255
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aac4a49 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 561
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aac4495 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 244
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff95649748 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 290
20  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff956495b9 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
21  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff954f034c aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 531
22  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff954f00c9 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 31
23  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff954effd3 aeProcessAppleEvent + 295
24  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff912a2c6e AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aabdeb2 _DPSNextEvent + 2249
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aabcf68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9aab2bf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
28  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010f280d5e ChromeMain + 6702910
29  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010f28057c ChromeMain + 6700892
30  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010f2ba063 ChromeMain + 6937155
31  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010ecb7391 ChromeMain + 634225
32  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x0000000111c76b79 ChromeMain + 50701657
33  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x0000000111c79122 ChromeMain + 50711298
34  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x0000000111c73247 ChromeMain + 50687015
35  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010f22e06d ChromeMain + 6363725
36  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010f22d716 ChromeMain + 6361334
37  com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010ec1c662 ChromeMain + 66
38  com.google.Chrome               0x000000010ec0df39 main + 9
39  com.google.Chrome               0x000000010ec0df24 0x10ec0d000 + 3876
```

Comment: Are you having any issues with other apps?

Comment: No, just in google chrome.

Comment: Start Chrome from the Terminal with the follow command, and post the output here. Hopefully this will give us more information: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

Comment: `2015-06-09 15:22:13.460 Google Chrome[17946:1899575] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {23 1} for CTRun 0x7ff764da70c0. Ignoring the run...
Segmentation fault: 11`

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Chrome using free AppCleaner (http://www.freemacsoft.net/), then
clean your system using another free utility - OnyX (http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) and then try reinstall Chrome again.

Comment: @Prince, just to be clear - did my answer help or you have found another solution?